# Application don't get nearby places

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, geolocation, location

I am a beginner in Kotlin and I am trying to build a nearby places application.

My application should work like this:

First page is a list of different type of place (like ‘Restaurant’, ‘Museum’, ‘Bar’, ‘Marker’…) If the user clicks on one of these types, they are sent to a new page with a map. On this map, they can see the type of places that they choose, near them. To do that, I followEd a YouTube channel, which does something similar to me but with a different design.

Here are the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tI4dV9n6-yE&t=2937s

- Part 1 : Setup Google Maps
- Part 2 : Get current location
- Part 3 : Get Nearby Places

(I’m at part 3)

My problem is the following: I create the first page with the listview, and when I click on an element I get a map with my location, but I don’t get nearby places.

When the application runs I can see on the console this line:

> URL_DEBUG: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=0.0,0.0&radius=10000&type=museum&key=MY_API_KEY

I don't understand why latitude and longitude are at 0 when I call the `getUrl()` function. Can someone help me?

Comment: I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the calls to `nearByPlace` run before the location callback is executed. Try placing this code:

```
val placeChoix = intent.getStringExtra("CHOIX")
when(placeChoix)
{
    "Restaurants" -> nearByPlace("restaurant")
    "Bars" -> nearByPlace("bar")
    "Musées" -> nearByPlace("museum")
    "SuperMarché" -> nearByPlace("supermarket")
    "Hopital" -> nearByPlace("hospital")
    "Magasins" -> nearByPlace("shopping_mall")
}
```

Inside the callback:

```
private fun buildLocationCallBack() {
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
            mLastLocation = p0!!.locations.get(p0.locations.size-1) //get last location

            if(mMarker != null)
            {
                mMarker!!.remove()
            }

            latitude = mLastLocation.latitude
            longitude = mLastLocation.longitude
            //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "latitude: $latitude \n longitude : $longitude", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val latLng = LatLng(latitude,longitude)
            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("Votre position")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
            mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

            //move camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11f))

            val placeChoix = intent.getStringExtra("CHOIX")
            when(placeChoix)
            {
                "Restaurants" -> nearByPlace("restaurant")
                "Bars" -> nearByPlace("bar")
                "Musées" -> nearByPlace("museum")
                "SuperMarché" -> nearByPlace("supermarket")
                "Hopital" -> nearByPlace("hospital")
                "Magasins" -> nearByPlace("shopping_mall")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!